# Visual Studio 6 - Application suddenly dies leaving no error messages

Tags: visual-c++

Some weeks ago I made some modifications to an old "Visual C++ 6" multi-threaded application. Since then, the application randomly disappears from the screen without leaving any error messages (not even in the event viewer). I am in big trouble and dont know how to find the problem.

The code was written with try/catch to catch every exception, and for years I've been able to trace my programming mistakes thanks to exception messages and the like. It's the first time I see my application die with no error messages.

Could somebody please give me a tip

Answer (score 1):

Run your program attached to the debugger and debug it.  Assuming that doesn't work,

1. Using your source control system, revert to a "known good" version.
2. Perform a binary search through the changes made since that version to find the offending change, or, if you are unable to do this, start making the changes one at a time until you find the problem.

Comment: Did you mean to CW this answer?

Comment: @Paul:  Yes.  I've started CWing all of my answers to soft, unanswerable, or otherwise silly questions.